# Run-time creation of typed pointer?

Tags: delphi, pointers, record

Would there be a way to create a typed pointer to a record during run-time?

E.g. achieve the same in run-time as the pMyRecord assignment in

```
TMyRecord = record
  s1: string;
  s2: string;
end;

TpMyRecord = ^TMyRecord;
```

...

```
 var pMyRecord: TpMyRecord;
 begin
   New(pMyRecord)
```

but then without the `TpMyRecord = ^TMyRecord` declaration.

I know I could use GetMem and FreeMem but I want to keep life-time management of the strings.

The question is a bit out there, I know, and I could just use the `TpMyRecord = ^TMyRecord` declaration, but I'm curious if there were a run-time way to do this (although I'm suspecting it to be too much of an RTTI hassle).

Comment: `var pMyRecord: ^TMyRecord;` fixes that without declaring the pointer type explicitly.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you give an example of how you'd use this, if it existed? Where do you find yourself needing to call `New` on a variable whose type you don't know until run time?

Comment: @RobKennedy It's actually a matter of not requiring the consumer of a certain library to make the extra declaration. So just to avoid having to take that extra step. Programmers are lazy. ;)

Comment: @LURD In the unlikely event you weren't joking, you just moved that type declaration from the interface part to the variable declaration part of that procedure. You, silly, you.

Comment: Domus, well I think I answered the question :-)

Comment: You seem not to want to declare the pointer type separately (although that's best), and you seem not to want to build the type when declaring the variable, either. So what type will your variable have, and how will you use the variable, once it has a value?

Comment: @RobKennedy The type will be TMyRecord and I want to create it through New without declaring a pointer type during compile-time. David seems to have solved that. Which is very impressive.

Comment: I don't really see how my answer helps that. It would be useful if the type was only know ln at runtime. If the type is known at compile time you should use New and Dispose.

Comment: If the type is `TMyRecord`, then `New` doesn't enter into it at all. Declaring the variable creates the record automatically. There's no dynamic memory allocation. David's answer declared the variable with the pointer type (and a lot more code than it would require if you'd just declare the pointer type), which isn't what you want.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The type is known by the caller, but the object that receives it, copies it without knowing its type. Other objects, that are clients of this object, do know the type and use it. But the object in the middle of all this has responsibility to destroy it in the end.

Comment: @RobKennedy Then tell me how to make a copy of a record whose type you don't know and destroy the copy reliably at the end?

Comment: I don't see what that has to do with this question, Domus. You said you declared the variable using the record type. Thus, you know the type. How did "a record whose type you don't know" enter the picture?

Comment: @RobKennedy I explained it in one of the comments. The calling class knows the type, the receiving one doesn't.

Comment: I asked "what type will your variable have?" and you said "the type will be TMyRecord." What's the real answer?

Comment: @RobKennedy My apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible with a bit of trickery. Here is an demonstration program:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  TypInfo;

type
  PMyRecord = ^TMyRecord;
  TMyRecord = record
    s1: string;
    s2: string;
  end;

var
  SystemNew: function(Size: NativeInt; TypeInfo: Pointer): Pointer;
  SystemDispose: procedure(P: Pointer; TypeInfo: Pointer);

function GetSystemNewAddress: Pointer;
asm
  MOV EAX, offset System.@New
end;

function GetSystemDisposeAddress: Pointer;
asm
  MOV EAX, offset System.@Dispose
end;

var
  p: PMyRecord;
  typeInfo: Pointer;

begin
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;

  @SystemNew := GetSystemNewAddress;
  @SystemDispose := GetSystemDisposeAddress;

  typeInfo := System.TypeInfo(TMyRecord);
  p := SystemNew(TypInfo.GetTypeData(typeInfo).RecSize, typeInfo);
  p.s1 := 'foo';
  p.s2 := 'bar';
  SystemDispose(p, typeInfo);
end.
```

The `New` function is an intrinsic function, and receives special treatment from the compiler. When you call `New` the compiler emits code to call `System._New` passing the size of the type, and its type info. In turn `System._New` allocates the memory, using the size of the type, and then initializes the instance using the type info.

The code in the program above shows how to make those calls from your code. The tricky part is obtaining the address of `System._New`. The code here shows how to do it for the 32 bit Windows compiler.

If you want to call `New` you will also want to call `Dispose`. This is also an intrinsic and is treated quite similarly. The code above shows how.

It should go without saying that this relies on implementation details that may change in the future.

Comment: Is this *"without the `TpMyRecord = ^TMyRecord` declaration"* ?.

Comment: That's crazy excellent witchcraft. Did you have that answer on standby or did you just work that out? In any event, it's very impressive. Many thanks!

Comment: @sertac I included it for convenience to assign to the record. I could not bothered trying to construct a run time mechanism for that part as well and I struggle to imagine a scenario where that would be useful. Bit obviously the calls to New and Dispose don't rely on that type declaration.

Comment: @Domus I didn't have it on standby because I must admit I can't see any use for this. I knew all the details though so piecing them together was easy.

Comment: @David, Ok thanks for explaining, yes you could leave the memory pointed by an untyped pointer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm sure there are better solutions for this, but it's part of an attempt to obtain as much loose coupling as possible. The record is stored in a class that has no idea of its type (beyond that it's a record), but is responsible for its creation and destruction. Since I'm now trying to figure out how to assign an existing record to this newly created one, without knowing type (and avoiding to use Move), I might just abandon the entire concept.

Comment: Copying could be a little tricky. Have you considered generics? Do they not make the problems disappear?

Comment: I have considered generics, but since there are many consuming objects all with different record types, I'm a bit afraid for code-size explosion. And I don't want the classes to be known by the consumers, They'd each time have to declare one, which I don't consider loose coupling.

Comment: If you don't want the record types to be known by the consumers, why don't you simply declare a `function NewBla(params): Pointer` and `procedure DisposeBla(bla: Pointer)` for each of these types and otherwise simply pass them around as opaque pointers? To the consumer, they are opaque types, but for you, it is much easier to call `New(PBla(result))`etc. inside these functions, where `PBla`is a pointer to your internal `TBla` type. Then you don't need the trickery (well ,execpt for the cast) in your code but can still keep the types opaque for the user.